# How use lerp python function at driver expression?

Tags: python, animation, drivers

I'm trying to use a lerp function, but Blender gives an error. What is the problem?

The problem appears exactly when I try to do something with a lerp. The rest of the driver works fine.

[image]

Comment: You can always ask a question @ZargulTheWizard

Comment: The problem ist that there is no function called `lerp()` that you can call like this. Could you please explain how you intend to linearly interpolate in your use case?

Comment: Usually the lerp function take 3 arguments anyway, what are you trying to do ?

Comment: @brockmann okay I asked https://www.sololearn.com/Discuss/2743533/?ref=app